# Thesis 2 Theme Skin Editor not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

My theme (Thesis 2) Skin Editor doesn't work. When I follow Thesis 2 -> Skin Editor, I can see the following (provided in the screenshot). But the buttons Html, Css, Images, Data manager, Canvas are not working.
How can I solve this issue?

The wordpress top dashboard panel is already not working here. I really don't know what's wrong.[image]

Comment: deactivate your plugins one by one until error not resolved

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! It works! You can add an answer via "Answer a question button" and I'll accept it as right one!